# Asp.NET MVC 5/ WebApi - Angular 6 routing problem

Tags: asp.net, angular, routes

Currently, I'm writing a new client app for my application. (It's just a mock application of client service).

I've decided to learn something new and use Angular 6.I have a trouble with an routing. I'm hosting my application on IIS. Locally it works perfect but when I publish this app to the my test server I meet some difficulties.

Currently I support two versions of clients apps.

```
public ActionResult Index(string version = null)
    {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(version))
        {
            if (version == "V1")
                return View("Index", new HomeViewModel
                {
                    Version = settingsProvider.CurrentApiVersion
                });
            if (version == "V2")
                return View("AngularApp");
        }
        return View("AngularApp");
   }
```

http://localhost:59098/   -> new angular app client V2

http://localhost:59098/?Version=V1   -> old V1 client

**Asp.net routing**

```
ublic class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //enable attribute routing
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new
            {
                serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
                    {
                        return !url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/App-", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                    })
            }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
    }
}
```

**Angular routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'App-Documentation', pathMatch: 'full'}
      ,
      {
          path: '',
          component: LayoutComponent,
          children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: DocumentationComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'App-Documentation',
      component: DocumentationComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'App-Settings',
      component: AdministrationComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'App-Chat',
      component: ChatComponent
    }
  ]
   },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'App-Documentation' }
  ];
```

**1)**

This application has webapi routes without prefix and I can't change that (automatic tests and etc.)

```
[RoutePrefix("")]
public class ClientApiController : ApiBaseController
{
```

So I decided to create angular routing with **App-** prefix

When I created asp.net route constraint for default route

```
serverRoute = new ServerRouteConstraint(url =>
                    {
                        return !url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/App-", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                    })
```

and new rule for angular app

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "angular",
            url: "{*url}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});
```

locally it works perfect.
When i put http://localhost:59098/App-Settings in url it routes me to angular app to App-Settings.

But when I put this on the server

https://serverName/pullApplicationName/appName/App-Settings

[image]

I'dont know why routing can't handle that on the server.

**2)**
I guess it's a problem with angular routing on iis

When I put 
https://serverName/pullApplicationName/appName/

It works greate and it routes me to app but, when I put

https://serverName/pullApplicationName/appName

It routes me to

https://serverName/pullApplicationName/

It works beacause I have angular route

```
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'App-Documentation' }
```

But it's weird because it routes me to angular app with patttern appName

Then when I decide to use angular routing I got

https://serverName/pullApplicationName/App-Settings.

Do you know how to fix this things?